#  changing the left padding of a DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView to populate the data from a database. I have two "types" of rows, one displays parent, and second displays children. I would like the children to be left-indented so it will have to visual look of a "parent-children" relationship.

How can this be done?

Comment: It might be possible by handling the cell and row paint events. You'd have to get comfortable with using the `Graphics` class.

Comment: Yeah I think I might be able to somehow distinguish between parent and children graphically. For example, presenting different different color might be a solution. I was hoping to move the row a bit; that would be really good representation of the architecture. If I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: If you decide to just change the row color I can post and answer for the best way to do that. Let me know if you want it.

Comment: I probably will, for example if parentID != 0 change the background color to grey and font color to white for the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you  said you might just highlight child rows, here's some code to do that. You could also just change the backcolor on the RowsAdded event, but this way is neater and faster (the row doesn't have to be painted twice).

Handle the DataGridView's RowPrePaint event:

```
private void dataGrid_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    // use whatever your row data type is here
    MyDataType item = (MyDataType)(dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem);

    // only highlight children
    if (item.parentID != 0)
    {
        // calculate the bounds of the row
        Rectangle rowBounds = new Rectangle(
            dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible ? dataGrid.RowHeadersWidth : 0, // left
            e.RowBounds.Top, // top
            dataGrid.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) - dataGrid.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 1, // width 
            e.RowBounds.Height // height
        ); 


        // if the row is selected, use default highlight color
        if (dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
        {
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rowBounds);
        }
        else // otherwise use a special color
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.PowderBlue, rowBounds);


        // prevent background from being painted by Paint method
        e.PaintParts &= ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background;     
    }   
}
```

I actually usually prefer to use a gradient brush for special highlighting:

```
using (Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rowBounds, color1, color2,  
       LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rowBounds);
}
```

Where `color1` and `color2` would be whatever colors you choose.